# Где придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения нельзя заменить причастным оборотом?

Tags: спп, причастный-оборот

А) Необходимый эмпирический и теоретический базис, который служит своего рода критерием обоснованности культурологических гипотез, определяет границы их применения. 
 Б) В России в период экономических реформ оказались декриминализованы многие деяния, которые в новых экономических условиях утратили общественную опасность.
В) Производственная система цеха — лишь одна из структур, в которой протекает жизнедеятельность работника предприятия.
Г) Древнейшими очагами музыкального образования на Руси были школы богослужебного пения, а также певческие хоры (крылосы), которые возникли в 11 веке в Смоленске, Новгороде, Владимире и в др. городах.

Comment: @pantera1979, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось, либо предложите свой вариант ответа.

Answer (score -1):

В предложении под литерой В.